# Type 'FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Getting error with RTK query:

> Type 'FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetDataQuery();

return (
   <div>{error}</div>
);
```

How to solve it? What should I display instead?

Comment: how about checking the error exist first and rendering the error message `{error && <div>Error: {error.message}</div>}
`

Comment: @TulaMagar Then I get `Property 'message' does not exist on type 'FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError'.   Property 'message' does not exist on type '{ status: number; data: unknown; }'.`

Comment: hold on, are you trying to display the error message or ? `{error && (
  <div>
    Error: {error instanceof FetchBaseQueryError ? error.status : error.message}
  </div>
)}
`

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the docs on [Type Safe Error Handling](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#type-safe-error-handling):

**Type safe error handling**

A. When an error is gracefully provided from a base query, RTK query will provide the error directly.

B. If an unexpected error is thrown by user code rather than a handled error, that error will be transformed into a `SerializedError` shape.

Users should make sure that they are checking which kind of error they are dealing with before attempting to access its properties. This can be done in a type safe manner either by using a type guard, e.g. by checking for discriminated properties, or using a type predicate.

When using `fetchBaseQuery`, as your base query, errors will be of type `FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError`.

When using `fetchBaseQuery`, the error property returned from a hook will have the type `FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError | undefined`. If an error is present, you can access error properties after narrowing the type to either `FetchBaseQueryError` or `SerializedError`.

Example:

```
import { api } from './services/api'

function PostDetail() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = usePostsQuery()

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  // Possible values of error: 
  // FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError | undefined
  // 1) Checking if error is NOT undefined:
  if (error) {
    // 2) Checking if error is FetchBaseQueryError based on
    // discriminated property 'status':
    if ('status' in error) {
      // you can access all properties of `FetchBaseQueryError` here
      const errMsg = 'error' in error ? error.error : JSON.stringify(error.data)

      return (
        <div>
          <div>An error has occurred:</div>
          <div>{errMsg}</div>
        </div>
      )
    // 3) We're left with the 3rd case, SerializedError:
    } else {
        // you can access all properties of `SerializedError` here
        return <div>{error.message}</div>
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

simple answer

```
'message' in error ? error.message : ''
```

or if you want the error property instead of message

```
'error' in error ? error.error : ''
```

Check out the [in operator's documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing). It allows you narrow down a type. In this case you want to know if its 'FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError' since message or error only exist on one of them it will narrow it down to the correct type.